# how to join object in for loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem

```
if (is_array($item)) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($item['quantity']); $i++) {
            $object->setCurrency($currency);
            $object->setName($item['title'][$i]);
            $object->setQuantity($item['quantity'][$i]);
            $object->setPrice($item['price'][$i]);
            $arr[$i] = (array) $object;
        }
  d($arr);
 }
```

when I do var_dump it result as below:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [PayPal\Common\PPModel_propMap] => Array
            (
                [currency] => USD
                [name] => Bed Bed
                [quantity] => 1
                [price] => 700
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PayPal\Common\PPModel_propMap] => Array
            (
                [currency] => USD
                [name] => Bed Bed
                [quantity] => 1
                [price] => 70.78
            )
    )
```

)

I tried some property array in php but not success, i want to result should be look like as below
I tried some property array in php but not success, i want to result should be look like as below

```
 Array
    (
    [0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
        (
            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                (
                    [currency] => USD
                    [name] => Bed Bed
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 700
                )

        )

[1] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
    (
        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
            (
                [currency] => USD
                [name] => Bed Bed
                [quantity] => 1
                [price] => 70.78
            )

    )
```

)

Can you help me?

Comment: maybe create a new instance of that object?

Comment: Also, where is the object declared?

Comment: `$arr[$i] = (array) $object;` try to change this line to `$arr[$i] = $object;`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
if (is_array($item)) {
    $arr = array();
    $count = count($item['quantity']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $object = new stdClass();
        $object->setCurrency($currency);
        $object->setName($item['title'][$i]);
        $object->setQuantity($item['quantity'][$i]);
        $object->setPrice($item['price'][$i]);

        $arr[] = $object;
    }

    var_dump($arr);
}
```

(I added some tiny improvements & initializations) and remove your **cast as array** (`(array)$object` => `$object`).

Answer (score 0):

@Etienne

here result when used case for user

```
Array
(
[0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
    (
        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
            (
               [currency] => USD
            [name] => Bed Bed
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 70.78
            )

    )

[1] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
    (
        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
            (
                [currency] => USD
            [name] => Bed Bed
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 70.78
            )

    )
```